# how to upload python application with google apps?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, web, upload, dns

I developed one application and upload on example.appspot.com

now i want to upload it on www.example.com

what to do???

pls reply fast..

Answer (score 3):

Actually, your application has to be hosted by GAE, but you can [set a domain for it](http://code.google.com/intl/pt-BR/appengine/docs/domain.html).

Comment: i do that but i got one image who shows welcome to example.com 
so how to see my application on example.com???
any settings required??

Comment: If you read the link posted by CrociDB and follow the steps it will exactly show you how to setup your GAE app and domain. It might take up to 48 hours for the DNS change to be applied, so you might not see it straightaway.